# How can I simply the following Bayes probability?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I know $p(x_2|y)$, and I can calculate $p(x_1|y)$

How can I simplify $p(y|x)=\frac{p(x|y)}{p(x)}\cdot p(y)$ in terms of the above?

Where $x \in \{x_1,x_2\}$

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated ! Your question lacks context, can you please clarify what are $x_1, x_2, x \text{ and } y$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to atleast also know the pmf/pdf of $y$, $p(y)$. The denominator is the marginal distribution of $x$,

$$p(y|x_1) = \dfrac{p(x_1|y)p(y)}{\int p(x_1|y)p(y)dy}$$ or a $\sum$ in the denominator if $y$ is also discrete.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks yeah $y$ is discrete $ y \in \{0,1\} $